# Zsh: Conda/Pip installs command not found

Tags: python, pip, zsh, conda

So I installed **Anaconda** and everything is working. After I installed it I decided to switch to `oh-my-zsh`. I am now getting:

```
zsh: command not found: conda
```

when trying to use `pip` or `conda` installs

```
echo $ZSH_VERSION
```

> 5.0.5

I have added to my `zshenv.sh`

```
export PATH ="/Users/Dz/anaconda/bin:$PATH"
```

What is it that I'm missing?

Comment: I think this is all you really need to answer this: `source ~/miniconda/bin/activate` then run `conda init zsh` assuming you installed conda. If not check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49118277/what-is-the-best-way-to-install-conda-on-macos-apple-mac

Comment: set the source using same command for as suggested by @Charlie Only change for anaconda installation is use this command :  `source ~/opt/anaconda3/bin/activate` path `/opt/anaconda3` should be your installed location of anaconda please check and modify.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

It appears that my PATH is broken in my `.zshrc` file.

Open it and add :

```
export PATH="$PATH;/Users/Dz/anaconda/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/Users/Dz/.rvm/bin"
```

Doh! Well that would explain everything. How did I miss that little semicolon? Changed:

```
export PATH="$PATH:/Users/Dz/anaconda/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/Users/Dz/.rvm/bin"

source ~/.zshrc
echo $HOME
echo $PATH
```

We're good now.

Comment: why aren't you running `.bach_profile`?

Answer (score 200):

I found an easy way. Just follow below steps:

1. in terminal, enter `vim ~/.zshrc`
   [image]
2. add `source ~/.bash_profile` into .zshrc file
   [image]
3. and then in terminal, enter `source ~/.zshrc`
   [image]

Congratulation for you!!! ㊗️

Comment: `source ~/.zshrc` is not enough, needed indeed to add `source ~/.bash_profile` so thanks!

Comment: this worked for me on  Macbook pro-2019 with macOS Catalina, thank you

Comment: This is no longer working in 2020 - add this to first line of ~/.zshrc  `export PATH="/usr/local/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"`

Comment: macbook air 2019 model, catalina: works perfectly, many thanks

Comment: Perfect solution with OSX 11

Comment: this is not the cleanest solution. There are better solutions like the one of @edwardyaho or mine below.

Comment: WARNING. This is not without risk. Doing this completely messed up my prompt. But my faulty for following steps devoid of an explanation.

Comment: The default .bash_profile is now called .profile which can be seen in the HOME directory.

Comment: How is this actually working? And @Ben2209, how is this not the cleanest solution/what is wrong with it?

Comment: @seeker_after_truth Sourcing .bash_profile when you actually are not using bash but zsh is some kind of workaround. Conda offers a command that inserts the right code in the .zshrc directly. See my answer below.

Comment: This messed up my terminal and the bash was not getting exited after "Process completed" because apparently adding this line results in infinite loop and the terminal hangs.

Comment: weird, why do we need to run bash_profile?

Comment: no this is dangerous. Better open `.bashrc` and copy the conda specific commands and paste in `.zshrc`.

Comment: This only works if your .bashrc isn't doing anything incompatible with zsh, so as others say, it's risky.

Comment: This is a lifesaver, want to give it a 1000 upvotes and bookmark it for life !

Answer (score 182):

If you are on macOS Catalina, the new default shell is zsh. You will need to run source /bin/activate followed by conda init zsh.
For example: I installed anaconda python 3.7 Version, type `echo $USER` to find username

```
source /Users/my_username/opt/anaconda3/bin/activate
```

Follow by

```
conda init zsh
```

or (for bash shell)

```
conda init
```

Check working:

```
conda list
```

The error will be fixed.

Comment: If you install anaconda for all users (like me) use `source /opt/anaconda3/bin/activate`

Comment: This works perfectly on M1 Mac with BigSur 11.6, thanks!

Comment: After running above commands you'll start to get `(base)` in front of your zsh when a fresh zsh window is opened. To remove that run `conda config --set auto_activate_base false` . Open new zsh and try `conda list`

Comment: why aren't you running `.bach_profile`?

Comment: how do I find the path to `source /Users/my_username/opt/anaconda3/bin/activate` not sure where conda installed it's stuff...

Comment: @CharlieParker You should have had the option to specify this during installation. The default for me was /Users/me/anaconda3, but you should be able to find where it is simply by searching in Finder :)

Comment: Using Mac rosetta, the binaries are in /usr/local/anaconda3/bin

Comment: Thanks. It worked from me on MAC "source /Users/my_username/opt/anaconda3/bin/activate"

Comment: installing by homebrew: `source /opt/homebrew/anaconda3/bin/activate`

Comment: How to automatically run `source /Users/x/anaconda3/bin/activate`? It works for me, however, it's a bit tedious to do this every time I open a new terminal window... Tried to add it in the ~./zshrc but that did not work

Answer (score 54):

As of today Nov 4, 2018 all the following methods works, install the zsh with:

```
sh -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/master/tools/install.sh)"
```

**Not** recommending brew installation for zsh:

```
brew install zsh zsh-completions
```

P.S: Tried with with brew and brew install under the root and is not an wise idea to do so due the security and all time anything related will need to be started under sudo so better is to stick with **curl** or **wget**.

to make work conda in OS X with oh-my-zsh installed is to add path as following and will work.

> Find the python paths so can see if you installed Anaconda2 or Anaconda3: `where python` or `which python` will result in similar output:

```
/usr/bin/python
/Users/"username"/anaconda/bin/python # # previous path for anaconda
/Users/"username"/anaconda3/bin/python # # previous path for anaconda3
/Users/"username"/opt/anaconda/bin/python # # for current path anaconda
/Users/"username"/opt/anaconda3/bin/python # # for current path for anaconda3
```

> one line config command for Anaconda:

```
echo -e '# >>> anaconda conda config >>> \nPATH="$HOME/opt/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc && source ~/.zshrc && conda init
```

> For using with miniconda for one line config command for arm64 : Apple
> Silicon miniconda3 (M1 & M2), part of installation for MPS
> acceleration [tensorflow-metal](https://developer.apple.com/metal/tensorflow-plugin/), pytorch ):

- Miniconda install:

  curl -O https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-MacOSX-arm64.sh
  sh Miniconda3-latest-MacOSX-arm64.sh
- one line config command for arm64 : Apple Silicon:

  echo -e '# >>> anaconda conda config >>> \nPATH="$HOME/miniconda3]/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc && source ~/.zshrc && conda init

> Note: Anaconda do not recommend to add manually paths per following:
> [Should I add Anaconda to the macOS or Linux PATH?](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/faq/)

We do not recommend adding Anaconda to the PATH manually. During installation, you will be asked “Do you wish the installer to initialize Anaconda3 by running conda init?” We recommend “yes”. If you enter “no”, then conda will not modify your shell scripts at all. In order to initialize after the installation process is done, first run source /bin/activate and then run conda init.

```
Note:

Replace <path-to-anaconda> with the actual path of your installed Anaconda file.
```

> What is the default path for installing Anaconda?

If you accept the default option to install Anaconda on the “default path” Anaconda is installed in your user home directory:

- Windows 10: C:\Users<your-username>\Anaconda3\
- macOS: /Users//anaconda3 for the shell install, ~/opt
  for the graphical install. See [installing on macOS](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/mac-os/).
- Linux: /home//anaconda3

If your username includes spaces, as is common on Windows systems, you should not accept the default path. See In what folder should I install Anaconda on Windows?

> I already have Python installed. Can I install Anaconda?

You do not need to uninstall other Python installations or packages before installing Anaconda. Even if you already have a system Python, another Python installation from a source such as the `macOS Homebrew` package manager and globally installed packages from `pip` such as `pandas` and `NumPy`, you do not need to *uninstall, remove, or change any of them*.

Install Anaconda or Miniconda normally. There is no need to set the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable.

*To see if the conda installation of Python is in your PATH variable:*

- On macOS and Linux, open the terminal and run echo `$PATH`.
- On Windows, open an Anaconda Prompt and run echo `%PATH%`.

*To see which Python installation is currently set as the default:*

- On macOS and Linux, open the terminal and run `which python`.
- On Windows, open an Anaconda Prompt and run `where python`.

To see which packages are installed in your current conda environment and their version numbers, in your terminal window or an Anaconda Prompt, run `conda list`.

For detailed info on adding manually see below info:

[Finding your Anaconda Python interpreter path](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/tasks/integration/python-path/)

> vi ~/.zshrc **or** gedit ~/.zshrc

> Anaconda updated to use similar to Anaconda Enterprise edition **paths**: `/opt/...`
> **@update Dec 2021: For Anaconda3 at field `# User configuration` add:**

```
PATH="$HOME/opt/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
```

> For Anaconda:
> at field `# User configuration` add:

```
`PATH="$HOME/anaconda/bin:$PATH"`
```

> For Anaconda2 at field `# User configuration` add:

```
  `PATH="$HOME/anaconda/bin:$PATH"`
```

> For Anaconda3 at field `# User configuration` add:

```
`PATH="$HOME/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"`
```

> or replace "username" with your username:

```
`PATH="/Users/"username"/anaconda3/bin:$PATH`
```

---

> According to documentation [Installing on macOS](http://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/mac-os/#macos-graphical-install) we add add in
> `~/.zshrc` instead of `.bashrc or .bash_profile`
>
> - Add export `PATH="/<path to anaconda>/bin:$PATH"` in ~/.zshrc
> - Or set the PATH variable: `export PATH="/<path to anaconda>/bin:$PATH"`
>
> Replace `“<path to anaconda>”` with the actual path to your Anaconda
> installation.
>
> This methods are working on ubuntu/Centos7/MacOS as well (just
> close/reset the terminal once you are completing the changes) than
> just type *conda* to test.

---

> Per @truongnm comment just source after adding the path: "I pasted the
> path from my bash_profile, and don't forget to `source ~/.zshrc`"

Comment: I pasted the path from my bash_profile, and don't forget to source ~/.zshrc

Comment: > source ~/.zshrc definitely helps!

Comment: why aren't you running `.bach_profile`?

Comment: Because question is tagged as zsh …

Answer (score 27):

The anaconda installer automatically writes the correct PATH into the ~/.bash_profile file. Copy the line to your ~/.zshrc file, source it with `source ~/.zshrc` and you're good to go.

Comment: Thanks copying the PATH  in ~/.bash_profile to ~/.zshrc worked for me.

Comment: This worked for me. Thanks. Just for clarity: I copied there are several lines in .bash_profile installed by anaconda that I copied and put into .zshrc. Everything worked as expected afterwards.

Comment: on my basrc, it is `[ -f /opt/miniconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh ] && source /opt/miniconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh`

Comment: This answer is gold.

Answer (score 19):

Answer for macOS 11 (Big Sur) in 2021

After installing Anaconda, run:

```sh
source /opt/anaconda3/bin/activate
conda init zsh
```

then close and reopen the Terminal window. The shell prompt should have a `(base)` prefix.

> NOTE: I found many articles online saying to update the PATH variable,
> but Anaconda actually recommends against doing so and running the two
> commands above instead, which they state in their documentation.

[Source](https://towardsdatascience.com/install-anaconda-on-macos-big-sur-9fbd7c4b6c24)

Comment: Thanks, this is the cleanest solution for me!

Comment: works on linux manjaro too, thanks

Comment: Same, worked well, thanks!

Comment: This should be the top scoring solution.

Comment: this one is the best solution for me after migrate from bash to zsh

Comment: I'm running OS 14.2.1. When I run the command above, I get `source: no such file or directory: /opt/anaconda3/bin/activate`. Any idea why?

Answer (score 14):

I had this problem on my Catalina OSX after I installed my Anaconda distribution as well.

**This solution worked for me on macOS Catalina as of October 19, 2019**

Step 1. Check if .bash_profile is available on your home folder, if not:

- Go to Terminal
- Type `cd ~/` to go to your home folder (if you are not on your home folder)
- Type `touch .bash_profile` to create your new file under the your home folder

Step 2. Check if file `.zshrc` is available on your home folder, if not:

- Go to terminal and type `nano ~/.zshrc`
- Type in the following line into the newly created .zshrc file: `source ~/.bash_profile`
- Now to save the file in nano just hit `ctrl`+`X`.
- It will prompt *"Save modified buffer (ANSWERING "No" WILL DESTROY CHANGES)?"*. Just type in `Y`

Step 3. Check if .bash_profile and .zshrc files are created on your home folder. If yes, in terminal type in `source ~/.zshrc`

Answer (score 14):

You should do the following:
 1. `/home/$USER/anaconda/bin/conda init zsh` (or `/home/$USER/miniconda3/bin/conda init zsh` if you use miniconda)
 2. `source ~/.zshrc` (or just reopen terminal)

Why this answer is better than others?

- You shouldn't reinvent the wheel: there is already command in conda to activate, all you need to do is to call conda with full path
- Maybe `~/.bash_profile` doesn't exist (my case, only `~/.bashrc`)
- You can have bash-specific config inside `~/.bash_profile`
- You don't need manually paste and export any pathes

Answer (score 11):

This is all I had to add to add get anaconda working for zsh.

```
echo ". /anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" >> ~/.zshrc
source ~/.zshrc
```

Answer (score 10):

If this problem occurs on a mac, then type the following commands:

```
source <path to conda>/bin/activate
conda init zsh
```

This will modify your zshrc accordingly (or create it if it does not exist).

This solution comes from the official [anaconda doc](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/install/macos.html).

Answer (score 9):

I just ran into the same problem.
As implicitly stated inside the .zshrc-file (in your user-root-folder), you need to migrate the pathes you've already inserted in your .bash_profile, bashrc or so to resolve this.

Copying all additional pathes from .bash_profile to .zshrc fixed it for me, cause zsh now knows where to look.

```
#add path to Anaconda-bin
export PATH="/Users/YOURUSERNAME!!/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"

 #N.B. for miniconda use
export PATH="/Users/YOURUSERNAME!!!/miniconda3/bin:$PATH"
```

Depending on where you installed anaconda this path might be different.

Comment: If anyone is here dealing with reinstalling after the Catalina OS update this is probably what you're looking for.

Answer (score 8):

You need to fix the spacing and quotes:

```
export PATH ="/Users/Dz/anaconda/bin:$PATH"
```

Instead use

```
export PATH="/Users/Dz/anaconda/bin":$PATH
```

Comment: https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/faq#id9

could it be the docs themselves are wrong? I spent an hour until i stumbled upon this.

Answer (score 5):

If anaconda is fully updated, a simple "conda init zsh" should work. Navigate into the anaconda3 folder using

> cd /path/to/anaconda3/

of course replacing "/path/to/anaconda/" with "~/anaconda3" or "/anaconda3" or wherever the "anaconda3" folder is kept.

To make sure it's updated, run

> ./bin/conda update --prefix . anaconda

After this, running

> ./bin/conda init zsh

(or whatever shell you're using) will finish the job cleanly.

Answer (score 4):

1. Find the right version of your `anaconda`
2. Put it to `~/.zshrc` via command `vim ~/.zshrc`

   - Anaconda 2 `export PATH="/User/<your-username>/anaconda2/bin:$PATH"`
   - Anaconda 3 `export PATH="/User/<your-username>/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"`
   - Or if you install Anaconda in root directory:
   - Anaconda 2 `export PATH="/anaconda2/bin:$PATH"`
   - Anaconda 3 `export PATH="/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"`
3. Restart the zsh `source ~/.zshrc`

Comment: The root direcotory! Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

MAC OS Users:

1. `brew install anaconda`
2. Add `export PATH="/usr/local/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"` to top of `~/.zshrc`
3. `source ~/.zshrc` OR restart terminal

Test it. Bingo Bango.

Answer (score 3):

Key is to activate conda after you installed it from executing the official install (e.g. with sh or something). So this:

```
source ~/miniconda/bin/activate
conda init zsh
```

---

My whole installation:

```
# - install python
# install brew
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
#  install wget to get miniconda
brew install wget

# get miniconda
wget https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-MacOSX-x86_64.sh -O ~/miniconda.sh
bash ~/miniconda.sh -b -p $HOME/miniconda

# source /Users/my_username/opt/anaconda3/bin/activate
source ~/miniconda/bin/activate
conda init zsh
conda update -n base -c defaults conda
conda install conda-build

conda create -n iit_synthesis python=3.9
conda activate iit_synthesis
#conda remove --name metalearning2 --all
```

inspired from:

- https://askubuntu.com/questions/505919/how-to-install-anaconda-on-ubuntu/1412558#1412558
- - https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/install/linux.html
- mac provides the nice renaming and downloading to location: https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/install/macos.html
- [How to install wget in macOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33886917/how-to-install-wget-in-macos)

Answer (score 2):

I simply added the anaconda3 path to $PATH in .zshrc which did the trick for.

My environment : Catalina / clean Anaconda install / iTerm / zsh / oh-my-zsh

First locate your conda installation:

```
> find ~/ -name 'conda' -print
```

(on my system: ~/opt/anaconda3/bin/conda)

Then add that path to PATH in the .zshrc file

```
export PATH="opt/anaconda3/bin":$PATH
```

Answer (score 2):

run the following script provided by conda in your terminal:

`source /opt/conda/etc/profile.d/conda.sh` - you may need to adjust the path to your conda installtion folder.

after that your zsh will recognize `conda` and you can run `conda init` this will modify your .zshrc file automatically for you. It will add something like that at the end of it:

```sh
# >>> conda initialize >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
__conda_setup="$('/opt/conda/bin/conda' 'shell.zsh' 'hook' 2> /dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/opt/conda/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        . "/opt/conda/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
    else
        export PATH="/opt/conda/bin:$PATH"
    fi
fi
unset __conda_setup
# <<< conda initialize <<<
```

source: https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/install/rpm-debian.html

Answer (score 2):

For Linux

1. Open `.bashrc`
2. Copy the code for `conda initialize` and paste it to `.zshrc` file
3. Finally run `source .zshrc`

Comment: Great explanation! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Simply copy your Anaconda `bin` directory and paste it at the bottom of `~/.zshrc`.

For me the path is `/home/theorangeguy/miniconda3/bin`, so I ran:

```
echo ". /home/theorangeguy/miniconda3/bin" >> ~/.zshrc
```

This edited the `~/.zshrc`. Now do:

```
source ~/.zshrc
```

It worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

1. Open your ~./bashrc
2. Find the following code (maybe something similar) that launches your conda:

```sh
    # >>> conda init >>>
    # !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
    __conda_setup="$(CONDA_REPORT_ERRORS=false '/anaconda3/bin/conda' shell.bash hook 2> /dev/null)" if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        \eval "$__conda_setup" else
        if [ -f "/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
            . "/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
            CONDA_CHANGEPS1=false conda activate base
        else
            \export PATH="/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
        fi fi unset __conda_setup
    # <<< conda init <<<
```

3. source ~/.zshrc
4. Things should work.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using an M1 mac or versions after macOS 11 then here's how you can go:

```
source /opt/anaconda3/bin/activate

conda init zsh
```

After this you can restart your shell and it will be working fine

Answer (score 0):

So I discovered that in your ~/.zshrc file, there was a commented line,

`# If you come from bash you might have to change your $PATH
 # export PATH=$HOME/bin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH`

Just uncomment the export statement and all your previous bash_profile commands will also be there. If that comment does not exist, you can also just add that export statement to .zshrc file.

Answer (score 0):

None of these solutions worked for me. I had to append `bash` environment to the `zsh`:

```
echo 'source ~/.bash_profile' >> ~/.zshrc
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to terminal PREFERENCES, then PROFILES tab, then under the STARTUP section within the SHELL tab, check the white boxes for RUN COMMAND and RUN INSIDE SHELL. Clear any text in the RUN COMMAND input area, then add the command below and restart the terminal:

source ~/.bash_profile; clear

Comment: This is for MacOS but may work for others as well.

Answer (score 0):

## TL;DR

<kbd>⚠</kbd> Using this script will modify your `.zshrc` file (which is what we want, but just be warned).

<kbd>★</kbd> Anytime you see a file with `.*rc` it means it is a **run command** that essentially runs some start up instructions, and in this case, stuff you need for your shell to know so it does what you want it to.

Assuming you have `conda` installed already, the following works:

```bash
$ source path/to/your/conda/activate
(base) $ conda init zsh
```

For example, the path to my particular conda installation is `/Users/username/opt/miniconda3/bin/conda`

So my shell commands looked like this:

```bash
$ /Users/username/opt/miniconda3/bin/activate
(base) $ conda init zsh
```

---

## Details

You type `conda` into your shell running zsh and it gets mad:

```bash
$ zsh: command not found: conda
```

Your `zsh` shell does not come preconfigured to recognize `conda`. We know this because there is nothing in your `.zshrc` file to indicate it knows `conda` at all. You have to *tell your shell* (in this case `zsh`) that you want this to happen. The `conda` team knows this, so they [made a command for such a need](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/commands/init.html). But, first you have to activate `conda` manually like you would a `virtualenv` (don't worry about this last statement if it confuses you).

So you activate `conda` manually by using the `source` command:

```bash
$ source path/to/your/conda/activate
(base) $
```

Since paths can differ here, I used a made up path but your path probably looks something like `/Users/username/opt/.../activate`.

Next, you run a `--dry-run` of `conda init` because you do not want to modify things without knowing what you are modifying (in my opinion). An output example is shown below but it may not match yours:

```bash
(base) $ conda init zsh --dry-run
no change     /Users/username/opt/miniconda3/condabin/conda
no change     /Users/username/opt/miniconda3/bin/conda
...
```

If you are happy with what will change, run the same command without the `--dry-run` flag.

Finally, restart your shell. It should open with something like this:

```bash
(base) $
```

Now you can use `conda` as you like anytime you start up your shell.

Answer (score -1):

I see a lot of good answers, but still I couldn't resolve the issues on `Mac Sonoma 14`. **I recommend finding the path of the condo first** and then exporting it or using it in the profile.

Find conda path

```
which conda
```

Expected output

```
/usr/local/anaconda3/bin/conda
```

Now we have two options to set the PATH.

**Option 1** - export the path only for the current shell

```
export PATH="/usr/local/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
```

**Option 2** - add the path to bash profile and execute source

```
nano ~/.bash_profile
export PATH="/usr/local/anaconda3/bin:$PATH" # add to .bash_profile
source ~/.bash_profile # read and execute the commands
```

And you're done

Answer (score -2):

FYI for anyone having this same issue keep in mind that you need to make sure that you have the right version of anaconda in that export path:

```
anaconda2 or anaconda3
```

Spent way too long on that minor issue.

Answer (score -2):

this solved it for me, and is sure to work
add this to ~/.zshrc

```
export PATH=path_to_anaconda_bin:$PATH
```

the answer