# How to install wget in macOS?

Tags: macos, wget, osx-elcapitan, libssl, libressl

I try to install wget in MAC OS 10.11.1 but when I run `./configure --with-ssl=openssl` I get this error:

```
configure: error: --with-ssl=openssl was given, but SSL is not available.
```

How to resolve this problem in OSX 10.11.1?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Apple Stack Exchange](http://apple.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306).

Answer (score 669, accepted):

**Using brew**

First install [brew](http://brew.sh/):

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
```

And then install wget with brew:

```
brew install wget
```

**Using MacPorts**

First, download and run [MacPorts installer](https://www.macports.org/install.php) (.pkg)

And then install wget:

```
sudo port install wget
```

Comment: I only had to run `brew install wget --with-libressl` and it worked flawlessly. Thanks

Comment: Got this when installing? `Warning: wget: this formula has no --with-libressl option so it will be ignored!`

Comment: Or simply use:    `brew install wget`  . Homebrew will install any necessary dependencies

Comment: Honestly, this is the most painless answer. Use brew! In brew we trust!

Comment: Ehhhh what about those of us who don't use Brew and instead use MacPorts or something?

Comment: Oh wow, Macports is very easy installation as well. I've edited it in. Just do `sudo port install wget`.

Comment: Error: invalid option: --with-libressl

Comment: I'm on macOS Big Sur version 11.4 and ```brew install wget``` worked perfectly. Great question. Perfect answer. Thanks a ton

Comment: macOS Monterey v12.5 Only `sudo port install wget` worked for me.

Comment: homebrew should now be installed with `/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"` via https://brew.sh/

Comment: 'brew install wget' isn't working in Ventura 13.1

Answer (score 13):

For macOS Sierra, to build wget 1.18 from source with Xcode 8.2.

1. Install Xcode
2. Build OpenSSL

   Since Xcode doesn't come with OpenSSL lib, you need build by yourself. I found this: https://github.com/sqlcipher/openssl-xcode, follow instruction and build OpenSSL lib. Then, prepare your OpenSSL directory with "include" and "lib/libcrypto.a", "lib/libssl.a" in it.

   Let's say it is: "/Users/xxx/openssl-xcode/openssl", so there should be "/Users/xxx/openssl-xcode/openssl/include" for OpenSSL include and "/Users/xxx/openssl-xcode/openssl/lib" for "libcrypto.a" and "libssl.a".
3. Build wget

   Go to wget directory, configure:

   ```
   ./configure --with-ssl=openssl --with-libssl-prefix=/Users/xxx/openssl-xcode/openssl
   ```

   wget should configure and found OpenSSL, then make:

   ```
   make
   ```

   wget made out. Install wget:

   ```
   make install
   ```

   Or just copy wget to where you want.
4. Configure cert

   You may find wget cannot verify any https connection, because there is no CA certs for the OpenSSL you built. You need to run:

   **New way**:

   If you machine doesn't have "/usr/local/ssl/" dir, first make it.

   ```
   ln -s /etc/ssl/cert.pem /usr/local/ssl/cert.pem
   ```

   **Old way**:

   ```
   security find-certificate -a -p /Library/Keychains/System.keychain > cert.pem
   security find-certificate -a -p /System/Library/Keychains/SystemRootCertificates.keychain >> cert.pem
   ```

   Then put cert.pem to: "/usr/local/ssl/cert.pem"

   **DONE**: It should be all right now.

Comment: I mean... this works, but it's a lot tougher than just using homebrew

Comment: @StormeHawke for someone who doesn't want to use homebrew

Answer (score 6):

You need to do

> ./configure --with-ssl=openssl --with-libssl-prefix=/usr/local/ssl

Instead of this

> ./configure --with-ssl=openssl

Answer (score -2):

I update mac to Sierra , 10.12.3

My wget stop working.

When I tried to install by typing

```
brew install wget --with-libressl
```

I got the following warning

> Warning: wget-1.19.1 already installed, it's just not linked.

Then tried to unsintall by typing

```
brew uninstall wget --with-libressl
```

Then I reinstalled by typing

```
brew install wget --with-libressl
```

Finally I got it worked.Thank God!

Answer (score -10):

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

And then install `wget` with brew and also enable `openressl` for TLS support

```
brew install wget --with-libressl
```

It worked perfectly for me.

Comment: This is exactly the same as the accepted answer and is older, yet has got a vote of -1 whilst the accepted answer has a vote of 122.  Why?

Comment: @giles123 this answer was submitted 15-Jun-2017, while the accepted answer was submitted 24-Nov-2015. I guess this answer is getting downvoted because it's a shameless copy of the accepted answer

Comment: Oops, sorry, I read "Jun 15" as "June 2015"!  Don't know where I thought the day had gone.  :">