# How to install wget in macOS catalina 10.15.7?

Tags: ssl, openssl, homebrew, wget, macos-catalina

i try to install wget in MAC OS 10.11.1 but when I run ./configure --with-ssl=openssl I get this error:

configure: error: --with-ssl=openssl was given, but SSL is not available.

how to resolve this ?
macOs catalina 10.15.7

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install wget in macOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33886917/how-to-install-wget-in-macos)

Comment: no sir. i can't  install xget using brem install xget. so i tried 2nd. method using xcode but till now i did not get any result. above error occur

Comment: The point of that post is that you need to provide `--with-libssl-prefix` to point at Apple's custom version of OpenSSL.