# Installing GeoPy in PyCharm (on MacOS)

Tags: python, pycharm, geopy

I need your help for installing the module GeoPy in PyCharm.

When I execute my project, there is this error :

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'geopy'

I haven't found the package GeoPy in PyCharm, so I have tried to install it with this command:

```
pip install geopy-1.17.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
```

The installation seems to be correct. But in PyCharm, it always says "No module named 'geopy'". Does someone know how can I make ssure that GeoPy is installed?

I work on MacOS High Sierra 10.13.6 with Anaconda and Python 3.

Comment: Can you try to run `conda install -c conda-forge geopy` in the Pycharm terminal?
Chances are you did not install the library in the correct environment.

Comment: I have tried but my terminal says `command not found: conda` but in PyCharm I have created a conda environment...

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/settings-tools-terminal.html
Try to set Setting -> Tools -> Terminal -> Shell path to the zsh one to see if it changes something. (I'm not a mac user but got the issue once on Windows. Trying to remember how I solved this)

Comment: My zsh is in the shell path... Thank you so much

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31615322/zsh-conda-pip-installs-command-not-found
This might help solving the `conda` command not found.

Comment: After many command lines, it doesn't want to work. I think that I install in the right environment... In the terminal, it says that geopy is already installed but it doesn't appear in the folder anaconda3.

Answer (score 0):

check out your project interpreter in:

```
settings >> Project >> Project interpreter
```

it seems like you are using an virtual environment, so you can add the `geopy` library using the `+` icon on the right bar.

**Edit:**

based on your environment path try this:

```
source /Users/nelly/.conda/envs/HiL-recommender/bin/activate
pip install geopy
```

Comment: hi there, @NellyBarret after clicking the `+` button, search for it, and you should find it.

Comment: I have typed geopy after clicking the button +, but nothing appears in the list (I have already installed shapely for example and works fine, but I can't find geopy in the list)

Comment: Wow! @NellyBarret could you comment the Project Interpreter address that the settings show you?

Comment: /Users/nelly/.conda/envs/HiL-recommender/bin/python

Comment: Hi, in bin there is no "activate" file so my terminal says "so such file or directory". Edit : but I have an activate file in /Users/nelly/anaconda3/bin/activate

Comment: @NellyBarret try this: `conda install -c conda-forge geopy`