# Conda commands not working in Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL)

Tags: windows, ubuntu, anaconda, conda, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I installed Anaconda3 in my windows environment and added

```
C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\Scripts
C:\Users\user\Anaconda3
```

to my windows environmental variables. Theoretically, this should also update my path in WSL like it does with visual studio code. However it didn't and now I can't run conda commands from the ubuntu terminal. I can't figure out how to fix this...thanks!

*It should be noted that I am also using zsh and oh my zsh by running the code

```
# Launch Zsh
if [ -t 1 ]; then
        exec zsh
fi
```

Inside my bashrc file

Comment: And how did you add those variables in Windows?

Comment: By editing the system environment variables and adding them to path

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. The issue was, that I had installed conda for windows and it seems it doesn't run fine with `wsl`. Try downloading and installing *conda for ubuntu* from the `wsl` command line interface and add the folders to the path. It worked for me.

This [link](https://gist.github.com/kauffmanes/5e74916617f9993bc3479f401dfec7da) helped me download conda from wsl command life interface.

Answer (score 0):

If path not added, export PATH="/Users/username/anaconda/bin:$PATH" to your .zsh_config file.

This link may help you 
[Zsh: Conda/Pip installs command not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31615322/zsh-conda-pip-installs-command-not-found)