# Windows Subsystem for Linux - conda: command not found

Tags: python, bash, anaconda, conda, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm using Windows 10 and recently installed Windows Subsystem for Linux.
Anaconda was already installed on my PC at that point.

When I try to run conda commands on Bash on Ubuntu on Windows I get the following error:

```
$ conda conda: command not found
```

Other related answers, such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44488349/windows-10-conda-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command?noredirect=1&lq=1) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53353415/conda-commands-not-working-in-windows-subsystem-for-linux-wsl) suggest adding

```
C:\Users\«user»\Anaconda3\Scripts
C:\Users\«user»\Anaconda3
```

to $PATH. But as you can see below, both are already included (I didn't add them manually):

```
$ echo $PATH | tr ':' '\n'
...
/mnt/c/Users/«user»/Anaconda3
/mnt/c/Users/«user»/Anaconda3/Scripts
/mnt/c/Users/«user»/Anaconda3/Library/bin
...
```

The following conda files are available in Anaconda3/Scripts:

```
conda.exe
conda-env.exe
conda-env-script.py
conda-script.py
conda-server.exe
conda-server-script.py
```

The commands work just fine in both PowerShell and cmd.

What am I missing?

[EDIT]: Corrected second URL and changed user to < user > in Anaconda3 paths above.

Comment: In your path the file is in `…/Users/Marco/…`, but you tell us that it is in `…/Users/user/…`.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor: user was meant as placeholder for the username. Changed it to <user> to make it clearer.

Comment: Try to run `conda.exe` instead of `conda`.

Comment: @Poshi: That did it. In other words the alias was missing. Added it to my ~/.bashrc. I guess it makes sense because Anaconda was installed before WSL. What if I had installed Anaconda on Windows after activating WSL? would it have created an alias automatically? Anyway, if you post that as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: @MarcoLeal I changed the other bit, to make it consistent

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try to run `conda.exe` instead of `conda`.

Windows assume `.exe` marks a file as executable, and ignores that extension when looking for the binary. Linux uses a flag, so any file can be an executable, and you need to provide the full name because there is no assumption on the extension.

Comment: Yes in Unix a name is a name. In windows you specify the implementation (`.exe`, `.bat`, `.com`, `.py`, …. In Unix we don't leak the implementation (we don't use file extensions. If we do it is just part of the name).

Answer (score 6):

Run conda init

```
.anaconda3/bin/conda init 
.miniconda/bin/conda init
```

Comment: For me `conda init zsh` fixed my problem as I had not realized I broke conda by switching from bash to zsh

Answer (score 3):

First start new terminal, Run
`cd`

now, travel to
`home/{your user name}/anaconda3/bin`

next run
,

```
./conda
```

if you get this output,
`usage: conda [-h] [--no-plugins] [-V] COMMAND ...`

Run this and your problem must be solved,
`./conda init`

Answer (score 2):

To add conda to Windows Subsystem **Linux**, this is the correct way:

```
curl https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh -o Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh
bash Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh
export PATH=$PATH:/miniconda3/bin
```

You will need to restart WSL for the env path to work.

Comment: Thanks for the `curl` line, it is spot on. But the `export` line does not work for me. Instead `export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/miniconda3/bin`