# Catalina zsh shell does not recognize "source" command

Tags: anaconda, zsh, macos-catalina, zshrc

I have a new Macbook Pro, pre-installed with Catalina, that I am trying to install Anaconda on. I was following the instructions on Stack Overflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31615322/zsh-conda-pip-installs-command-not-found) to fix the install. However, when I entered the following in the .zsh terminal:

```
source ~/.zshrc
```

I get the following error message:

```
.zshrc:1: command not found: Source
```

I have tried searching for a solution to no avail. My search results indicated that the source command is supposed to be built into the zsh shell, so this seems odd. Is this a known issue with the new MacBook Pros? Is there a fix for this error?

Comment: `source` or `Source`? Command names are case-sensitive.

Comment: Have you tried `conda init zsh`? Then restart the shell session after.

Comment: @chepner the command is entered lower case, but the error message uses upper case.

Comment: @merv The zsh shell doesn't recognize conda. I was trying to follow the fix linked in the OP so that it would recognize conda :)

Comment: Locate where the binary is and use `./anaconda3/bin/conda init zsh` (or whatever the path is).

Comment: @merv Weirdly, will not recognize conda... even if I actually cd directly into the directory containing conda and enter `conda init zsh` I get `zsh: command not found: conda`.

Comment: You need to use `./conda` to use a local binary.

Comment: That worked. Thank you! If you create an answer I'll green-check you :)

Comment: I propose closing this as a duplicate of [How to run Conda?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18675907/how-to-run-conda) You can upvote [my answer there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55526573/570918), which gives the same advice I provided here.