# __iterm2_precmd:type:50: bad option: -t after reinstalling Anaconda and doing 'source'

Tags: python, macos, shell, anaconda, iterm2

I upgraded my Mac OS and my Anaconda stopped working. I installed that and guess I had to do the whole `source` business so I followed these instructions:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/55860128/11252332

Now my Terminal displays `\[\](base) sandbar@Michaels-MacBook-Pro-2 ~ % \[\]
__iterm2_precmd:type:50: bad option: -t`

and I also got a message mentioning shopt. I just tried uninstalling iTerm2 and no dice. Any ideas?

Comment: Honestly, I would probably just uninstall anaconda and use a real Python installation. Anaconda is more work than its worth https://www.python.org/downloads/

Comment: Fixed it. Just had to reinstall iTerm2... again.

Answer (score 1):

I found that running the following command:

```
rm -f ~/.zshrc*
```

solved my issue.